# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d even if server tag is inside http

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to add CORS header to my app when deploying it to cloud via docker I get the error:
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

My nginx file

```
http {
 include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 server {
      root https://srm-master.nonprod.com;
      index index.html index.htm;
    set $cors "";
    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.ini.com)) {
      set $cors "true";
    }
    server_name .ini.com;
   location / {
   if ($cors = "true") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, 
        DELETE, PUT';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep- 
        Alive,Content-Type';
    }
   }
    }

   #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem has nothing to do with `Docker`, the cause of the error is nginx config. Because `nginx` allow only one `http` section, and it has been defined at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Remove the `http` section in your config, and it should be worked

```
server {
      root https://srm-master.nonprod.com;
      index index.html index.htm;
    set $cors "";
    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.ini.com)) {
      set $cors "true";
    }
    server_name .ini.com;
   location / {
   if ($cors = "true") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, 
        DELETE, PUT';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep- 
        Alive,Content-Type';
    }
   }
 }
```